# Change button's theme when sidenav toggles (angular-material)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design

I'm making a website using angular-material. There is a sidenav and a button. Whenever the sidenav toggles, I want the button to changes it's theme. Like, when the sidenav is open, the button's md-theme attribute is set to "cyan" and when sidenav is close, the button is set to another theme.

My html code:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="navCtrl" layout="column">
  <section layout="row" flex>
    <md-content flex class="md-padding">
      <div layout="column" layout-fill layout-align="center center">
        <md-button class="md-fab md-primary" md-theme="cyan" ng-click="toggle()" aria-lebel="Navicon">
          <md-icon class=""></md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </div>
    </md-content>

    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="nav"></md-sidenav>
  </section>
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial'])

.controller('navCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav) {
  $scope.toggle = function() {
    $mdSidenav('nav').toggle();
  };
});
```

I couldn't find a way to listen to this toggling and change the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  directive supports a md-is-open attribute that identifies a $scope or controller attribute value that is updated when the sidenav state is changed ( open <-> closed ).

Then, the $mdSidenav('nav').toggle() function returns a promise, so define the 'then' to set a 'theme' attribute in your controller that is referenced from the md-theme in your side-nav markup:

```
<md-button class="md-fab md-primary" 
           ng-click="toggle()" aria-label="Navicon"
           md-theme="buttonTheme" >
```

...

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="nav"
            md-is-open="isOpen"></md-sidenav>
```

...

```
 angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('navCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav) {
    $scope.isOpen = false;
    $scope.buttonTheme = 'cyan';

    $scope.toggle = function() {
     $mdSidenav('nav').toggle().then( function() {
         $scope.buttonTheme = ($scope.isOpen ? 'indigo' : 'cyan');
     });
  };
});
```